# PostgreSQL выборка строк из партиций

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Всем доброго дня. Имеется таблица со столбцами А и В:

```
А      | В
---------------
43126  | 43125
43127  | 43125
43101  | 43100
43102  | 43100
43103  | 43100
```

Необходимо выбрать строки (целевая выборка):

```
А      | В
---------------
43127  | 43125
43102  | 43100
43103  | 43100
```

То есть исключить из итоговой выборки только первые строки, у которых одинаковое значение в столбце В

Спасибо!

Comment: Что такое "первые" в данном случае? При какой сортировке?

Comment: Это не важно, при любой сортировке, то есть отброшена может быть любая строка

Comment: Вот "любая" - это ещё куда ни шло... хотя недетерминированность есть плохо и некошерно.

Comment: @ИльяНовоселов "Это не важно, при любой сортировке, то есть отброшена может быть любая строка" довольно необычное требование. Что за задача так решается?

Answer (score 2):

Нумеруем записи в пределах группы, отбрасываем первые номера.

```
select A, B
  from (
    select A, B, row_number() over(partition by B order by A) RN
      from table_x
  ) x
 where RN != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Выбираем записи, для которых существует запись с тем же `b` и меньшим `a`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t1.b=t2.b AND t1.a>t2.a )
```

Comment: ТС не уточнил, могут ли значения А повторяться для одного и того же B. Если могут, то твой запрос не будет работать.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Формально верно. Но если такие дубликаты существуют, то они неразличимы. В этом случае невозможно сказать, выполнено требование или нет.

Comment: Он писал - отбросить одну строку. Решение с `row_number` как раз так и сделает.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Я что-то Вас не понимаю. То, что запрос удалит все описанные дубликаты - я уже сказал, что это верно. Решение Mike - так я его давно плюсанул.

Comment: "В этом случае невозможно сказать, выполнено требование или нет" - я имел ввиду возможно сказать, что не выполнено ;)